# Mock class not working with Dynamic & Unique end-point

Tags: apex, unit-test, httpcalloutmock, mock

i am fetching some remote data into my salesforce and i am using "oauth_signature" in my end-Point URL for remote web services so my API URL is unique for every API request. my all functionality is working fine. But when i have tried to make test class for this with the help Mock class it always give following error:

```
System.NullPointerException: Static Resource not found: <null>
```

when i check my code again i found that i am assigning "multimock.setStaticResource" to a dynamic URL but when test class execute the main class then main class have some different "endPointURL". Then i have check my code with some static url and it works fine. can i add some while card to my  endPointURL or i need to do something else to run my Mock class.

my code is

```
MultiStaticResourceCalloutMock multimock = new  MultiStaticResourceCalloutMock();
multimock.setStaticResource(endPointURL, 'WooGetIndexMockResponse');
Test.setMock(HttpCalloutMock.class, multimock);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i am using Multiple response for WebServiceMock class so i need to assign a specific URL as following

```
multimock.setStaticResource(endPointURL, 'WooGetIndexMockResponse');
```

it seems to be not working with this way. then i created Single Request Mock class for each request. in this way we don't need to specify any end-Point URL and my test class working now.

Comment: I had exactly the same problem on a test that had run many times successfully in the past (last time over a year ago). Switching to StaticResourceCalloutMock() solved the problem. Thanks!

Comment: Do you actually say 'MultiStaticResourceCalloutMock'  does not work ?

Comment: See here https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_restful_http_testing_static.htm